# Installing Server with existing data on drives

Tags: server, partitioning, hard-drive, lvm, mediaserver

I have a Windows 7 HTPC which I'm planning on turning into a headless Home server using Ubuntu server as its OS. I'd like to use LVM.
My current set-up is 1x64gb ssd as the boot drive and 2xSATA drives for media storage.
I'd want Ubuntu to create a virtual drive comprising all 3 physical drives.
My problem is that I don't have enough hard drive space to back-up my existing files whilst installing the server.
Is it possible to install the server yet keep hold of my media?

Comment: Which drive is Windows installed on and do you keep your data on separate drives?

Comment: Hi, Windows (and programs) are on drive c (the ssd). Everything else is on the other two drives.

Comment: Then you can just install Linux on the C drive. Then you can raid the 2 disks together, then move everything to a folder on the drive.

Comment: Would my data be safe though through the process? I can't move the excisting files off the drives (I don't have enough spare disk space on any other drives at the moment) and not enough free space on the drives on the potential server to back everything up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to ask yourself the question: *"Should I back up?"* then the answer is a very probable:

### Yes!

So, head over here: [What's a good back-up strategy for 1 desktop PC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) and read it. (You're user type 4)

If you're unsure about yourself, you're likely to make mistakes, so a backup is needed even more!  Borrow a drive from someone, bribe someone to give you a drive or buy one if needed...  Heck, throw a party and have everyone bring their backup drive and distribute all your files among everyone!

If I was wrong about the back-up, come back here and down-vote my answer.  Don't be the next one in my long list of people I've told to back-up before continuing and then reading a comment a bit later: "You've just made me lose all my |@*$# data!" because they listened to someone else...